# Where are suggested edits being sent?

Tags: support, editing

As a low rep beta user, my edits are being made through the usual SE suggested edits mechanism. On most SE sites these would show up for high rep user or moderators sits in a queue to be approved or otherwise handled.

Since this site does not yet have any users with enough rep to access moderator tools and has no appointed moderators, who is handling this? Do these show up for the SE employee team?

I ask because I submitted a whole series of edits and have yet to see a single one be approved, and denied edits don't generate messages (and they don't show up in my user activity so they are hard to check on) so I don't know if something isn't wired up or if I'm doing something wrong or if somebody just hasn't gotten to them yet.

Comment: To follow up, a number of edits did go through so it was just a matter of timing and probably having SE staff all in the same time zone. Most of the other SE sites I work on have large Europe contingents that operate in the same time frame I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Exchange staff handles suggested edits in the earliest days until the pro tem moderator are appointed. There are already user who quickly move into the 500-point range, so they start picking up the workload, too.

The edits are suggested by users who have not yet earned full edit privileges, but we can only approve edits we know are correct and reject those that are obviously wrong. Many of the suggested edits will be contingent on how the community wishes to develop, and some are simply outside our decision to make. We are not experts on your subject. We can approve many of these suggestions, but oftentimes, some of those edits simply have to be left for other users to judge. Those users are on their way.

Answer (score 3):

Because we do not have either high rep users or pro-tem mods, they are currently being handled completely by SE staff members. The ones you will most likely see are Dori, HedgeMage, Shog9, Grace Note, Rebecca Chernoff and Robert Cartaino (did I miss anyone?). these folks are members of the SE Community team.